# Java split string not working as expected

Tags: java, regex

I am using jdk 1.6, I am trying to run below code but it is not working as expected:

```
String[] arr = ",,,,,".split(",");
```

But length of arr is shown 0.
I am expecting 6 elements in arr with all elements ""(blank) value.

Can anyone explain me reason behind this?
Is there any Regular expression available to fulfil my requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working as specified in [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) documentation. It clearly says:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

If you want to store empty strings, use overloaded version - [`String.split(regex, limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

So, you need to pass a *negative limit* here:

```
String[] arr = ",,,,,".split(",", -1);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you run

```
String[] arr = ",,,,,".split(",", -1);
```

the length of `arr` will be 6, because it also includes the empty String at the beginning.

Comment: +1 Sorry for the earlier misleading comment. Length will be 6 only. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String#split(String regex,int limit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,int%29) method.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.** If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

```
String[] arr = ",,,,,".split(",",-1);
```

As per the documentation of [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

Comment: please justify a downvote

Comment: @StefanBeike May be because there was a typo in my first post , used `1` instead of `-1` :P

Answer (score 1):

Run below code:

```
    string str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G";
    string[] arr = str.split(',');
```

you can get result as :

```
 string[0] = "A"

 string[1] = "B"

 string[2] = "C"

 string[3] = "D"

 string[4] = "E"

 string[5] = "F"

 string[6] = "G"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am excepted ",,,,," there is no space between two "," so when you trying to split the string , there is no string rather that ',', and split is not count the argument as a string. What you pass in argument place that String is not calculated. so it's showing length 0.

For more information please have look oracle document .

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29